# define "standard filter" in apache-poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, spreadsheet

I am using POI library to create spreadsheet editor app. I want to emulate excel's *standard filter* option using CTFilter and CTFilterColumn classes. I guess that CTFilter represents one filter (one line) from excel's *standard filter* dialog, but I can't see a way to set *Condition* and *Operator* values on it. I end up with something like

```
newCTFilter = filterColumn.getFilters().addNewFilter();
newCTFilter.setVal(referenceValue.toString());
```

How can I define that filtering values should be - for example - *less then* reference value ?

Comment: [CTFilterColumn](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/CTFilterColumn.java).addNewCustomFilters().addNewCustomFilter().setOperator([STFilterOperator.Enum](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/STFilterOperator.java#STFilterOperator.Enum) operator). But that's not the main problem The main problem is that storing the filter criteria is not enough. Excel will not hiding the not fitting rows automatically.

Comment: So I should use `CTCustomFilter` instead of `CTFilter`. Thanks. But I see that `STFilterOp‌​erator` enum contains only integer operators, and not string ones, like _starts with_ or _does not contain_ . Is there an enum which supports all operators which I can see in filter dialog in common spreadsheet editors like _Excel_ or _Libre Office Calc_ ?

Comment: You will need both `CTFilter` for applying default filter criterias and `CTCustomFilter` for custom ones. And the `*.xlsx` is a `ZIP` archive. So you can create a workbook with a sheet having autofilter with needed criteria applied and then simply unzip the `*.xlsx` file and have a look at `xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml`.  There you will find `<customFilter val="Name*"/>` for starts with and `<customFilter operator="notEqual" val="*blah*"/>` for does not contain. So wildcard `*` is used and operators in `STFilterOperator` are not only numeric. But:Filters in `Calc` are very different from `Excel`.